# MapThread on a nested Map

Tags: list-manipulation

A simple problem I am facing is here:

```
list1 = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {3, 4, 30}];
list2 = RandomReal[{10, 20}, {3, 4, 30}];
Map[Map[(# + 1+Min[#]) &, #] &, #] &/@list1;
```

works fine, but whenever such a nested `Map` appears, I think there might be a better solution than what I am doing here.
Now my problem is if I want to use a `MapThread` over the above function like the following, I stumble upon errors

```
MapThread[Map[Map[(# + 1/Min[#2]) &, #] &, #1] &, {list1, list2}];
```

Including this example and for even more nested situations, is there any general coding practice that is elegant, efficient and native to MMA functional language paradigm. Hope some one can help me with this type list manipulation here.

Comment: in your first example list2, does not do much. Could you provide a simple example of the result you'd like.

Comment: @ruebenko I dont expect any special result. I just used this example to highlight the situation one faces when using nested Map and question is if there is a way to use MapThread over such nested Map. Feel free to modify the question if you get a better example to make the `list2` important for the outer `MapThread`.

Comment: I think the problem is not nested map, but nested pure functions with `&`. Try using `Function` as @ruebenko answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for so, here are two ideas:

```
MapThread[
 f[#1, #2] &, {Map[Map[(# + 1/Min[#]) &, #] &, #] & /@ list1, list2}]
```

or

```
MapThread[
 Function[{x, y}, Map[Map[(# + 1/Min[y]) &, #] &, x]], {list1, list2}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `Function` is the best option to see if every thing is applied when you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a third argument to `Map` and `MapThread` to indicate at which level in the array the function should be applied. For example for you nested `Map` example you could do something like

```
Map[(# + 1 + Min[#]) &, list1, {3}]
```

For the `MapThread` example you could do something similar, e.g.

```
MapThread[(# + 1/Min[#2]) &, {list1, list2}, 3]
```

would apply the function in the first argument to elements in `list1` and `list2` at level 3.