# Nested lamdas: MapThreading a MapAt lambda

Tags: map, mapthread

Consider a set of (here) 3 series

```
r`data = Thread[{Range@4, # Range@4}] & /@ (10 Range@3);
(*{
{{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}}, 
{{1, 20}, {2, 40}, {3, 60}, {4, 80}},
{{1, 30}, {2, 60}, {3, 90}, {4, 120}}
}*)
```

The intent is to divide the second coordinate of each point in each series by some divisor `divs[[i]]`

```
r`divs = 10 Range@3;
(*{10, 20, 30}*)
```

I am currently achieving this as follows

```
r`f[x_] := #/x &
MapThread[MapAt[r`f@#2, #1, {All, 2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]
(*{
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}},
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}},
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
}*)
```

**How to eliminate `` r`f `` in favour of  directly nesting the division lambda `#/x &`, present in the `MapAt`, inside the `MapThread`?**

In other words how to correctly write something of the kind

```
MapThread[MapAt[#/#2 &, #1, {All, 2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]
                ^           
                |
                |
      should refer to second coord of point
             and not r`data[[i]]
```

Please note that I did go through similar questions (e.g. [MapThread on a nested Map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3338/mapthread-on-a-nested-map)) but couldn't apply their solutions to the present case.

Comment: How about ``MapThread[#1.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1/#2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]``?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MapThread[MapAt[z \[Function] z/#2, #1, {All, 2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]
```

or

```
MapThread[MapAt[Function[z, z/#2], #1, {All, 2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]
```

or

```
MapThread[Function[{x, y}, MapAt[#/y &, x, {All, 2}]], {r`data, r`divs}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, 
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
Transpose[Transpose[#]/{1, #2}] & @@@ Transpose[{r`data, r`divs}]

MapThread[Transpose[Transpose[#]/{1, #2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]

MapThread[ReplacePart[#, {i_, 2} :> #[[i, 2]]/#2] &, {r`data, r`divs}]

SubsetMap[Flatten[Partition[#, First[Length /@ r`data]]/r`divs] &, r`data, 
  {All, All, 2}] 

Module[{z = r`data}, z[[All, All, 2]] = z[[All, All, 2]]/r`divs;z]
```

all give

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}},
>  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}}
> ```

And... a Halloween special:

> [image]

```
☺[{r`data, r`divs}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, 
>  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}}
> ```

Comment: so one can't escape having to define the MapAt's func explicitly?

Comment: thnx for introducing me to spliced assignment!

Comment: @lineage, if you have to use `MapThread` + `MapAt` combination I don't know how we can avoid defining the function for the first argument of `MapAt`.  If  `MapAt` is not required, Carl's suggestion in the comments  is a clean way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

By using `ReplacePart` in place of any mapping function, there is no need to define any function, neither explicitly like your `` r`f `` nor as a pure function.

```
data = Thread[{Range @ 4, # Range @ 4}]& /@ (10 Range @ 3);
divisors = 10 Range @ 3;
ReplacePart[
  data, 
  {i_, j_} :> Module[{m = data[[i, j]]}, m[[2]] = m[[2]]/divisors[[i]]; m]]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, 
>  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, 
>  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In *Mathematica* version 12.1+ we can use [OperatorApplied](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html) to inject the outer argument into the inner function:

```
MapThread[MapAt[OperatorApplied[#/#2&][#2], #1, {All, 2}] &, {r`data, r`divs}]

(*
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}},
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}},
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
*)
```

[Curry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) from version 11.3+ does the same thing but is now considered obsolete.  For more details on these and related constructions, see [(197168)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197168/142).